# Which gas is used to fill the evacuation slides of modern aircraft?

Tags: emergency, equipment, evacuation

We have seen that after an emergency landing when the airplane needs to be evacuated promptly, [evacuation slides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evacuation_slide) get deployed immediately. I am not sure if normal air is being inflated in those slides or do they use some other gas in them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are filled with carbon dioxide, oxygen and nitrogen. See [here](http://www.airspacemag.com/flight-today/how-things-work-evacuation-slides-22196601/?no-ist) for reference.

From the linked article:

> Slides inflate with an initial boost from a canister of compressed
>   carbon dioxide and nitrogen. The canister provides only about
>   one-third the volume needed to inflate the slides. The remaining
>   volume is supplied by ambient air, channeled into the slides through
>   aspirators.
>
> When the inflation mechanism is triggered—by a lanyard pulled by the
>   slide as it tumbles from its storage case—gas from the canister
>   accelerates through the aspirators at high speed, creating a vacuum
>   that sucks ambient air into the aspirators through louvers. When the
>   slide is fully inflated, the louvers close.

Comment: In other words, they're filled with air.

Comment: @GdD: Mostly, but the initial compressed gas which provides the energy for filling is not air, but an oxygen-free mixture of carbon dioxide and nitrogen.

Comment: The way ambient air gets sucked in by the compressed gas flow is called ventrui effect.

Comment: @JustinKiang ... almost: It's called Venturi effect, after [Giovanni Battista Venturi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Battista_Venturi).