# If pure N2 (not gas generator) is used for evacuation slides, why is CO2 still needed?

Tags: emergency-slide

In the answers to [Aircraft Emergency Evacuation slide inflation system: Why is a mixture of CO2 & N2 used instead of pure N2?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23096/14897), it's mentioned that the nitrogen comes from a gas generator.

Yet the bottles I'm familiar with are labeled as "55% of N2 and 45% of CO2", how so?

The maintenance manuals do not mention a pyrotechnic gas generator. So if *pure N2* is used for evacuation slides, why is CO2 still needed?

Is there a technical reason, or simply a simplified labeling?

Comment: These a huge amount of detail on that other question, you should ask your questions as comments there rather than asking a duplicate question.

Comment: @GdD Someone just deleted my question in the comments because it was a question so...

Comment: You posted your question as an answer @electrotech, that's why it was deleted. In the future add a comment instead.

Comment: @GdD To be fair, you need a certain rep level to be able to comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aircraft Emergency Evacuation slide inflation system: Why is a mixture of CO2 & N2 used instead of pure N2?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23096/aircraft-emergency-evacuation-slide-inflation-system-why-is-a-mixture-of-co2)

Comment: @selectstriker2 Not really because he is saying that the N2 comes from the pyrotechnic gaz generator but the latter is not mentioned in the maintenance manual... It is clearly written that the bottle needs to be filled with half CO2 and half N2. So I don't really understand why we need this amount of gases

Comment: Peter's answer literally says "Now we can answer your question: Nitrogen is contributed both by the pyrotechnic gas generator and by the compressed gas and is produced from the dissociation of nitrous oxide (N2O)." Plus it answers every one of your questions pretty exactly.

Comment: @selectstriker2 That doesn't answer my question. If the N2 is produced by the dissociation of N2O, why the bottle is also filled with 55% of N2 ? Because as it is written, the dissociation produce N2 so we don't need to add more N2

Comment: @selectstriker2 that is the question he explicitly stated that he'd read and still didn't understand.

Comment: Nevermind, i'll go away without my answer, I just seem to bother you

Comment: @electrotech what maintenance manual are you referencing?

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate. From the [accepted answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23096/aircraft-emergency-evacuation-slide-inflation-system-why-is-a-mixture-of-co2/23104#23104) to the other question: "Carbon dioxide is added to dampen the exothermic dissociation and absorb some of the heat produced.".